# Image backup dual boot ubuntu 18.04 windows 7 drive

Tags: dual-boot

With your help I have ubuntu 18.04 working well enough that I would like to image or clone the the drive. It is a dual boot windows 7 drive. It seems that any suggestion that worked with other versions of ubuntu do not work with 18.4. I have tried a AOMIE standard boot disk and got nothing. Macrium reflect recovery media would not load the boot loader. Clonezilla live dvd recovered the boot section and ubuntu but not windows. Is there any way I can protect my drive.

Comment: How do you know that Clonezilla failed? Clonezilla should work (I have used it to clone whole drives). Troubleshooting tips: Boot into Windows and *reboot* (do not shutdown), This way it will not hibernate or semihibernate (those actions will make linux stay awaiy from it and Clonezilla is a linux tool). You can also change the setting in Windows to turn off Fast Startup which is the semihibernation I mentioned before, and the partition should be visible for linux.

Comment: I have my system set to never hibernate but I will give it a try.

Comment: Please tell us how you tested that Clonezilla failed to clone the Windows partition.

Comment: The windows partition failed to boot, sdudus and I don't think you were rude. I did get it working after two more tries. The second try I got a message that windows had not shut down properly. I thank you very much for your help. This forum has gotten me to a point that I think I will be able to function without having to install windows 10 on any more of my computers. I have it on my wife's laptop. The reason it is free is because it is so bad.